# suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found:'ns4.SaveCRRequest'

Tags: python, suds

Does anyone have inputs on how to debug or overcomes this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\move2ready.py", line 318, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\move2ready.py", line 268, in main
    success = moveToReady(prism, cr, pl_name)
  File ".\move2ready.py", line 153, in moveToReady
    retval = prism.saveChangeRequest(CR)
  File ".\move2ready.py", line 75, in saveChangeRequest
    request = self.soapclient.factory.create('ns4:SaveCRRequest')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 234, in create

suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'ns4:SaveCRRequest'
```

Following is the subroutine

```
 def saveChangeRequest(self, CR):
    request = self.soapclient.factory.create('ns4:SaveCRRequest')
    request['ChangeRequest'] = CR
    request['UserName'] = 'admin'
    response = self.soapclient.service.SaveChangeRequest([request])
    return response['ChangeRequestId']
```

Comment: Can you show us a link to the WSDL file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'ns4.SaveCRRequest'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945172/suds-typenotfound-type-not-found-ns4-savecrrequest)